# Symfony 4 - How to valid my token in controller?

Tags: php, symfony, security, controller, token

in a function of my controller, I initialize a form that I pass in parameter to a view. The form must then redirect to another action of my controller, like this:

**Controller : index()**

```
/**
     * @Route("/validation/absences", name="validation_index")
     */
    public function index(PaginatorInterface $paginator, Request $request, AbsenceService $absenceService)
    {
        $refusAbsence = new Absence();
        $formRefus = $this->createForm(RefusAbsenceType::class, $refusAbsence);
        $formRefus->handleRequest($request);
        return $this->render('validation/index.html.twig', [

            "formRefus" => $formRefus->createView(),
        ]);
```

My form action goes to this function :

```
 /**
     * Refuser une demande d'absence
     * 
     * @Route("validation/absences/refuser/{id}", name="validation_refuser")
     *
     * @param Absence $absence
     * @return void
     */
    public function refuser(Request $request, Absence $absence)
    {
        $token = $request->get('refus_absence')['_token'];

        if (!$this->isCsrfTokenValid('refus_absence__token', $token)) {
            throw new \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException('Accès interdit');
        }

        $commentaire = $request->get('refus_absence')['commentaire'];
        dd($commentaire);
    }
```

I get my token back with the request, but I can not get it to be validated. I still have the mistake.

Yet on Symfony's documentation, they say:

```
if ($this->isCsrfTokenValid('token_id', $submittedToken)) {
        // ... do something, like deleting an object
    }
```

And in my HTML, I've :

```
<input type="hidden" id="refus_absence__token" name="refus_absence[_token]" value="7bbockF5tz3r7Ne9f6dQB7Y5YMcwd1QRES4vHrhQEQE">
```

Comment: have you tried https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/csrf.html with forms because you don't have to manually add nor check this stuff, if you properly use forms to begin with...

Comment: I created my form with the formBuilder. And he also generates the token. But if I understand correctly, I do not need to perform this treatment? Knowing that in my function I can not use the line if ($ form-> isSubmitted () && $ form-> isValid ()) because I do not have access to the variable $ form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your receiving function, just recreate the form:

```
$form = $this->createForm(RefusAbsenceType::class, new Absence());
$form->handleRequest($request);
// also checks csrf, it is enabled globally, otherwise, recreate parameters
// in the createForm call.
if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) { 
    $absence = $form->getData();
    // do whatever ... persist and stuff ...
}
```